# Replace Oracle sql with postgres sql

Tags: postgresql, oracle

how to replace bitand function and decode oracle function in postgres sql?

```
select decode(bitand(p.privilege, 2), 2, 'true', 'false') as is_approver 
from person p;
```

tried below sql

```
select case ((p.privilege & 2 = 2))::int when 2 then 'true' else 'false' end as is_approver  
from person p;
```

Comment: Could you share the DDL for this table and some data?

Comment: By the way, this part becomes true or false: (p.privilege & 2 = 2). When you cast this to an integer, it becomes 1 or 0. But never 2

Comment: privilege numeric

Answer (score 0):

That should be

```
select (p.privilege::bigint & 2) = 2 as is_approver 
from person p;
```

Comment: getting this error Error: ERROR: operator does not exist: numeric & integer
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You may need to add explicit type casts.
SQLState:  42883
ErrorCode: 0

Comment: You need an extra type cast then.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `p.privilege & 2 = 2` will return a `boolean` value. If you can work with them inside your application, then all you need is:

```
select (p.privilege::int & 2) = 2 as is_approver
from person p;
```

If you really want string values for `true` and `false`, then you need to test the boolean value. Your expression is comparing the boolean value to an integer

```
select case 
         when (p.privilege::int & 2) = 2 then 'true'
         else 'false'
       end as is_approver
from person p;
```

Comment: getting this error 

Error: ERROR: operator does not exist: numeric & integer
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You may need to add explicit type casts.
SQLState:  42883
ErrorCode: 0

Comment: @user2400551: yes, indeed the bit operator is only defined for integers. Why is that column defined as `numeric` and not `integer`? But anyways, you can simply cast it. See my edit.